How to count gameObject on screen that was Instantiated
I want the player to have a limited amount of bombs that can be placed at a given time. I was able to limit the bombs, but when the gameObject is destroyed, I'm not sure how to change my bombCount with how I have my project setup.
My Player code is as following:
public GameObject bomb;
private int bombCount = 0;
public int maxBombs;

void Update()
{
  if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
  {
    if (ball.activeSelf)
    {
      if (bombCount < maxBombs)
      {
        bombCount++;
        Instantiate(bomb, bomb.position, bomb.rotation);
      }
      else
      {
        // Count the bombs on screen and
        // change bombcount to # of bombs
      }
    }
  }
}

I'm destroying the bombs in a seperate BombController file. My question is am I able to somehow subtract from bombcount when the object is destroyed or calculate how many bombs exist?
For reference this is my BombController code as well
public float timeToExplode = 0.5f;
public GameObject explosion;

void Update()
{
  timeToExplode -= Time.deltaTime;
  if (timeToExplode <= 0)
  {
    if (explosion != null)
    {
      Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
    Destroy(gameObject);
  }
}


You could look into object pooling and have it control the max level as well as not instantiate and destroy excessively

It can be done in different ways. One of the easiest in your case is to add a callback when your bomb is destroyed. Smth like:
in your bomb script
Action _onExplode;

public void SetOnExplode(Action onExplode)
{
    _onExplode = onExplode;
}

void Update()
{
  timeToExplode -= Time.deltaTime;
  if (timeToExplode <= 0)
  {
    if (explosion != null)
    {
      Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
    _onExplode?.Invoke();
    Destroy(gameObject);
  }
}

and in your main script
if (bombCount < maxBombs)
      {
        bombCount++;
        var bomb = Instantiate(bomb, bomb.position, bomb.rotation).GetComponent<BombController>();
        bomb.SetOnExplode(() => bombCount--);
      }

Overall, this way is far from good, but it will work and requires no significant changes from your side.
